# Bad Topology got after applying modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I have somewhat a bad topology on a model I made and it messes up with the shading and the material itself, it is a lot of edges that are intersecting with each other and I am not sure on how correctly I should fix this problem, I know how to fix it manually though. Do you have any recommendations that could make this go faster than just doing it manually?

Here are screen captures of my viewport  : [image: Bad Topology]

[image: Shading Problem]

[image: Topoly problem on other Faces]

Before I got the model, I applied a subsurface modifier and an array modifier with object offset, with a simple deform modifier on this model I don't know if my original topology was bad or not

[image: Based Model]

Comment: It looks like some faces were overlapping so you must have miscalculated the operation: if you kept 1/12 of a cylinder, you need to rotate the empty 30°: 30 x 12 = 360. Also make sure you didn't move the mesh from its origin and put the empty at the exact same point. Also I don't know why you used a Simple Deform on this one, as the segment is already deformed (1/12 of a cylinder), so rotating it 30° should make a 360°. But maybe share your file.

Comment: My bad, I didn't use a Simple deform modifier on this one. I have kinda moved to just apply the material and let it has it is for the moment since it's just a personal project, But I'm going to correct it in the near future, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your topology looks decent.
I'm pretty sure your array modifier didn't match start and end 100%. That created an overlap which you see in your 1. screenshot. Repairing this is tedious, it would be much simpler to go back to before you applied the array and fixing it in the base shape. If you use a segment of a circle or a sphere and then rebuild the circle/sphere from the modified segment with a circular array, make sure not to touch the outermost vertices, as they have to align perfectly in the end.

Comment: Hey, I didn't quite get the part of using a segment of a circle. You mean I should try to remake the hole I made of the cylinder using a segment of a circle or you mean the overall shape? I think what I may did wrong was touching the outer vertices, thanks I'm going to fix it

Comment: If you have a circle with 36 vertices, delete all but 4, do something to them and then use the array with 8 copies, you'll have a perfect fit again, if you use 40° rotation. If you move either the 1. Or the last vertex, it will not fit anymore. That's most likely what happened with your construct, probably by using a deform mod.

Comment: Oh okay thanks you I'm gonna try 